# Vertical align UITextlabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, alignment, detailtextlabel

I'm having issues with the vertical alignment in a UITableViewCell.

I'm using a **right detail** UITableViewCell in which the detailTextLabel contains multiple lines of text.
By setting the number of lines to zero I've managed to get the detailTextLabel to show all the text. This causes however the (left) text label to align in the top left corner instead of the center of the UITableViewCell.

Is there a way to use a TableViewCell in which the detailTextLabel contains multiple lines (In this case 2), and having the primary text label vertically centered?

[image: Current UITableViewCell alignment]

Comment: You should create your own prototype cell if your use case is different

Comment: Did you try setting the vertical align of the label? cell.textLabel.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter

Comment: @DejanSkledar I don't believe that `contentVerticalAlignment` is a property of a UITextLabel?

Comment: My bad, I mixed it up with the textField.

Comment: I should work with just changing the height of the textLabel.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` and make equal height of the two labels.

But I would prefer to create your own custom cell.

Comment: `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` is a property of a `UITextField`, not a `UILabel`